# why angularjs link function is never called?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

Angularjs link function is never called.

The source code is included in webpack bundle.

angular version is v1.6.6

```
import angular from 'angular';

const module = angular.module('app.directives.ax', []);

console.log('included directive');
module.directive('ax', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AEC',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      console.log('from directive');
      console.log('from directive xxx');
      elem.css('cursor', 'pointer');
      if (attrs.ngClick || attrs.href === '' || attrs.href === '#') {
        elem.on('click', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
        });
      }
    }
 };
});

export default module.name;
```

In the html template I have

```
<a class="default-link ax" ng-click="vm.delete(announcement.id)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
```

Comment: did you included `app.directives.ax` in your main `app` module?

Comment: yes, I did in the main module for the app not in the module for the controller where the directive is used.

Comment: Can you please replicate this issue in plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sutR1q6gtnIF8ugapHrh?p=preview)? I don't find any problem your code..

Comment: Please check browser console to get better clarity. Posted code looks like no issue. Check Is there any JS/Module reference error.Here is reference link: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wvb7melvMOgXh3FyoVnx?p=preview

Comment: @PankajParkar actually module name was not being included in dependencies properly. thanks.

Comment: My pleasure, thanks :)